# Selenium + TestNG + Java -> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng

I'm trying to run all my tests together instead one by one but I'm getting this error msg.

I'm using TestNG, Selenium 4.1.2, Java, chromedriver manage by `import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;` 
This is my BaseClass code, (where I create my setup() method):

```
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void before(@Optional("chrome") String browser) {

        try {

            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    
            if(browser.equals("chrome")){
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }else{
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
    
            driver.get(URL);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void after() {
        try {
            driver.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have 2 classes and If I run all my tests, they just run and pass the first test of every class and for the other ones just send me the same error `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id`.

NOTE: If I run one by one manually it works..!!
But if I run e.g "maven clean test" which will run a xml within POM, or right click on xml the same error msg appears, I've searched but all mention something about `driver.close() or driver.quit()` and anything works. Any help could be great :D

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Portafolio-Selenium-Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/config.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Selenium Project - Tests Cases">
    <test name="Header Page Tests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.HeaderPageTests" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Register Page Tests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.RegisterPageTests" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: where are you initializing `driver`?

Comment: Can you share your testng.xml file as well?

Comment: @cruisepandey updated on main comment :)

Comment: @GauravLad inside @beforeMethod, there is...  `driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Comment: Be sure to use driver.quit().  driver.close() won't necessarily quit the driver.  (some drivers will quit if there are no longer any browser windows open...)  It should also help to include a sleep after quitting the driver.  This gives the browser/driver time to cleanup things... especially the file that drops the sessionID.

Comment: @pcalkins `Thread.sleep()`  or `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));`
Using the first one got this error `Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?` second one got the same 'Invalid session ID'

Comment: You want a sleep after you quit.  ImplicitWait is not a sleep.  That is a polling loop for presence of element(s).  I'm not familiar with the framework, but it does sound like you are quitting the driver before your procedures are done.  Are you sure "AfterMethod" is what you want there?

Comment: Looking at the answer below, that seems to be correct.  "AfterSuite"... but it should also be helpful to sleep for 5 or so seconds between one driver quitting and another starting.

Answer (score 1):

probably the driver.close() in After suite will resolve the issue as there is no session when the other test being started.

Can you try by changing below,

```
@AfterSuite  
public void after_suite()  
{  
     try {
            driver.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
      
}
```

Comment: I tried and get a different error msg (I've tried that before), now I'm getting that the mouse hover action doesn't work but is weird because if I run just that test, it works..

Comment: That's a different error though, not sure and may be that particular function/step would give details

Comment: `Element is not able to click now (WaitForElementToBeClickeable Method) [[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (74b549057fe70f0d04d7c576e5a89df1)] -> xpath: //*[@id='top-links']/ul/li[2]/a/span[1]]org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.83)` This is the error I got.

Page tested is `http://opencart.abstracta.us` and if you look that xpath, there is
@dheeraj

Comment: You are trying to click the element which is no more available on the page, use proper waits or expected conditions to do the click action

Comment: I have tried with the new waits for selenium 4 using this`new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
` or this one 
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));` and the element is just present in the first test case, for the next ones it doesn't